# Coordinate recording in Cordova/PhoneGap produces odd results. Does my phone or the GPS satellite have anything to do with it?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps, geolocation

**Edit** - I plotted the reuslt using [mapcustomizer](https://www.mapcustomizer.com/)

I took the code from these [geolocation docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation), hooked up my phone and went around the block:

[image: My route around the 'hood]

Here's the code (barely modified from [this geoloc tutorial page](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.watchPosition)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    // document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    var watchID = null;

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Get the most accurate position updates available on the
        // device.
        var options = { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude +
                            '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;
    }

    // clear the watch that was started earlier
    //
    function clearWatch() {
      alert('STOPPING!');
        if (watchID != null) {
            navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
            watchID = null;
        }
    }

        // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
        //
        function onError(error) {
            var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
            element.innerHTML = '<h1 style="color:red;">ERRORED!</h1>' +
                                '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;       
        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="clearInterval(intervalio);alert('I WIN', 'SHOULD HAVE STOPPED')" style="color:red;font-size:25px;">STOP RECORDING YOU TARD</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      intervalio = setInterval(function() {
        onDeviceReady();
      }, 1000);
    </script>
    <p id="geolocation">Watching geolocation...</p>
    <button onclick="ondeviceReady();" style="color:green;font-size:25px;">STOP YOU IDIOT</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

tl;dr I used a `setInterval` and `clearInterval` on my own instead of using the example; I'd prefer to have used [.watchPosition](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.watchPosition) and [.clearWatch](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.clearWatch), but to my surprise `.watchPosition` returns `undefined` and therefore I can't stop it that way.

## Questions:

With the interval of 1000ms, the entire route (I was going like 10-20 mph like a responsible citizen) should be LITTERED with endpoints. Instead, my house is full of tags but the rest of the route is sparse.

Is it because I lost WiFi connectivity? How does a router know my position in 3D? Do the options I've specified:

```
var options = { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true };
```

Have something to do with the few points I'm seeing there? Does the GPS satellite have some kind of a ping with which it gets back to one's phone?